# Android SQLite returns -1

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm new here, and I'm working on my first android application for class.  Every time I use mDb.insert(), I get "-1" returned.

In brief, I have:

```
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
ContentValues intialValues; //I then .put() some stuff into intialValues 
return mDb.insert("mytable", null, initialValues);
```

And I get -1.

Answer (score 1):

Use `insertOrThrow` to get better debugging information. My psychic debugging powers say that you did not properly instantiate `mDb` using the writable method on the database open helper.